# PayPal Express Checkout with Currency from the Currency Switcher

Tags: checkout, paypal-express, multicurrency

Out of the box Magento's PayPal Express seems to always resolve the currency to the base currency (e.g. GBP). But on a website where a choice of currency is given to a customer using the currency switcher (e.g. GBP, EUR), if a customer chooses a currency other than the base currency (e.g. EUR), Magento always seems to pass the base currency to PayPal. My PayPal sandbox account can accept has both GBP and EUR.

Is there anyway to use the currency switcher's currency (i.e. quote_currency_code) as oppose to the base currency?